# xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'-PPxo-P24-FA')])[2] fails to select

Tags: selenium, xpath

This is what I have

```
<a href="/account/client/home/AccountID/1000000" class="managed_account_link being_setup" target="_self" title="Being Setup">1000000 Venelin-PPxo-P24-FAID-EUR</a>
```

want to write an XPath for the `a` based on its contained text. I tried the below but it does not work

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'-PPxo-P24-FA')])[2]
```

However, if I try with the below, it works

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'-PPxo-P24-FAI')])[2]
```

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.1 if that makes any contribution to my question.

Comment: Do you see that both xpaths are exactly same ?

Comment: @svasa: they are not.

Comment: @kushal Ok. I see. I need to have coffee.

Comment: Yeah.. I see no reason for this not to work, however, it does not...

Comment: @svasa: yeah you do that :P

Comment: The [2] would mean that you're trying to return the second match, but there's only one line of XML code shown.  It shouldn't make a difference in the results, though.  They should either both fail or both work, assuming that the second one works.  I could see a scenario where the first would would work but the second fail, but not the opposite, which is what you're showing.  Can you show a larger section of HTML code?

Comment: @BillHileman Thanks to your explanation, I finally found it!
The answer is - xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'-P24-')])[6]

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems your Xpath is incorrect

can you try following:

```
xpath = ("//a[contains(text(),'-PPxo-P24-FA')][2]")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, however, it still does not work.

Comment: I found the error. It looks like there are some hidden fields with the same text. The working code is xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'-P24-')])[6]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of the answers, guys!

However, I found the solution. It looks like the website contains the text some more times than I need it to. The working code is:

```
xpath=(//a[contains(text(),'-P24-')])[6]
```